# mysql query not working, but there is no error

Tags: php, mysql, database

here is my code

```
    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","boursdfdswmat","PfdXfdsfkd");
    mysqli_select_db("dbanme",$con);
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
    else {echo "connected";}

    $qry=mysqli_query("SELECT `title`, `created_date`, `user_id` FROM    `invoices` WHERE `user_id` = 123 ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 0 , 1");
    echo $res1=mysqli_num_rows($qry);
    $result=mysqli_fetch_array($qry);
    echo $result['0'];
    ///echo "hi";
    ?>
```

what wrong with these code. i dont get any results with these queries. please help me. thanks

Comment: add these lines, error_reporting ( E_ALL );
      ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 ); and see what happens.

Comment: @SureshKamrushi nothing.. only out put with this script is "connected"

Comment: what if you run the query directly in mysql (workbech or phpmyadmin)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two error in your code: invalid use of **mysqli_select_db** and invalid use of **mysqli_query**
for *mysqli_select_db*: parameters are wrong and *mysqli_query*: connection missed.

change you code to:

```
 <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","boursdfdswmat","PfdXfdsfkd");
    mysqli_select_db($con,"ghese_new");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
    else {echo "connected";}

    $qry=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `title`, `created_date`, `user_id` FROM    `invoices` WHERE `user_id` = 123 ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 0 , 1");
    echo $res1=mysqli_num_rows($qry);
    $result=mysqli_fetch_array($qry);
    echo $result['1'];
    ///echo "hi";
    ?>
```

Comment: He could also (as recommended in the docs) select the Database in the `mysqli_connect` call instead of calling `mysqli_select_db` afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The basic debugging method you want to do here is to determine if you have an error on the query string or did you actually connect to the database. Try to add the `mysql_error()` on your code like,

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","bouwmat","PXk(0")or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db("bouwmat_jos1",$con) or die(mysql_error());

$qry=mysqli_query("SELECT `title`, `created_date`, `user_id` FROM    `jos_listbingo_cart_cart_invoices` WHERE `user_id` = 896 ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 0 , 1")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: `mysqli_error($con)`, mysql_error is deprecated, don't think it will produce any error from mysqli (altho I might be wrong on the second statement).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have taken the old deprecated mysql_* functions and replaced them with mysqli, this does not always work.
Most procedural mysqli calls require the $link param (your connection), like:

```
 mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

or:
     mysqli_error($connection);

I do not think there is a `mysqli_connect_errno()` function, I can atleast not find one in the documentation (but i might be wrong, please correct me if so).
There is a `$mysqli->connect_errno` variable tho, but it should be called on your `$con` variable. But you are using the procedural version of mysqli, so you might just want to use the `mysqli_error($con);` call.

You also select the db in a mysqli_select_db call. This is not really wrong, but its recommended to select the database in the connection call:

```
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","boursdfdswmat","PfdXfdsfkd", "dbname");
```

Check the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php for more info.

Comment: The code was edited to not have such mistake after my post. I will tho edit my post with a few new pointers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","boursdfdswmat","PfdXfdsfkd","dbanme");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
     }
    else {echo "connected";}
    $qry=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `title`, `created_date`, `user_id` FROM    `invoices` WHERE `user_id` = 123 ORDER BY created_date DESC LIMIT 0 , 1");
    echo $res1=mysqli_num_rows($qry);
    $result=mysqli_fetch_array($qry);
    echo $result['0'];
 ?>
```

Try this code, mysqli_connect directly accept the database and query need connection object